Android Studio and apps developing
I've created an app using Android Studio , it worked just fine , i even tested it on my device
works perfectly yet it cannot be installed on my sister devices , it says that there is an issue with the package, i would love to know what's the issue and how to avoid it next time , thank you
enter image description here

How do you install it on your sisters device? As a Apk or with Studio? Check minSDK of your app and Android Version of target device.

as an APK , the API level is 35 of my Android Studio

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

If Google-apps-script has nothing to do with the question, remove that tag @RafikSemouma

@YingYang mentioned the nearest possible cause. You should also check your sister's device specifications, particularly the Android version or some features you specified within the app, which may also cause the issue.
